# Do I need to flush SMTP server? If yes, how to do it?

Tags: email, haskell, smtp

I have been struggling to send emails form within a Haskell program for a while now, tried to use HaskellMime library or something like that, but failed.
I installed HaskellNet recently and try using Haskellnet.SMTP module.
I tried sending an email with 'sendMail' command and get "user error(sendMail error)". I suppose it was because the SMTP server I used needed authentication.
I took a look at 'sendMail' source code and ended up writing this simple main: http://hpaste.org/47841
I checked each 'sendCommand' command and after the AUTH command I get a "Auth success" from the SMTP server, and 250 code from the other commands, as expected in the 'sendMail' source code.
The problem is I don't have any mails in my mailbox, so what am I doing wrong? The only thing I can think of, is that the mail is somewhere queued in the SMTP outgoing list and I need to flush the SMTP server, but that is not part of the 'sendMail' code, so I wonder...
Any help would be *greatly* appreciated, because I never thought it would be so hard to send an email :/
P.S. I use the exact same settings on my phone to send email with this SMTP server, same "smtp.sfr.fr", same ID (entire address), same password; and it works: I can send mails from my phone.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: Yes I had checked my spam folders, nothing was in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't comment on your use of HaskellNet, I've had great success using [SMTPClient](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SMTPClient) which you can grab from hackage with `cabal install SMTPClient`.

I've included the package's example to give you a sense of what using the library is like:

```
import Network.SMTP.ClientSession
import Network.SMTP.Client
import Network.Socket
import System.Time
import System.IO
import Data.Bits
import Data.IORef

myDomain = "example.com"
smtpHost = "hubert.blacksapphire.com"    -- <-- Your SMTP server here

-- This will send the author an email.  I don't mind!
main = do
    now <- getClockTime
    nowCT <- toCalendarTime now
    let message = Message [
                From [NameAddr (Just "Mr. Nobody") "nobody@example.com"],
                To   [NameAddr (Just "Stephen Blackheath") "unprintable.distances.stephen@blacksapphire.com"],
                Subject "I'm using SMTPClient!",
                Date nowCT
            ]
            ("Dear Sir,\n"++
             "It has come to my attention that this is an email.\n"++
             "Yours sincerely,\n"++
             "Mr. Nobody\n")
    addrs <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just smtpHost) Nothing
    let SockAddrInet _ hostAddr = addrAddress (addrs !! 0)
        sockAddr = SockAddrInet (fromIntegral 25) hostAddr
    putStrLn $ "connecting to "++show sockAddr
    sentRef <- newIORef []
    sendSMTP' (hPutStrLn stderr) (Just sentRef) myDomain
        sockAddr [message]
    statuses <- readIORef sentRef
    -- If no exception was caught, statuses is guaranteed to be
    -- the same length as the list of input messages, therefore head won't fail here.
    case head statuses of
        Nothing     -> putStrLn "Message successfully sent"
        Just status -> putStrLn $ "Message send failed with status "++show status
```

Comment: Well, thanks you for your answer, even a code in here,I wasn't asking for so much, but thanks you!  I will look into your code, but here is what I did so far (and it is working): I used telnet to connect to the SMTP server I wanted to use. Then I issued the commands needed to send an email, I ran into errors, I corrected them. Once I had them all correct, I just used 'sendCommand's to send the exact commands, same order, same arguments and it just worked. Here is the part of the code: http://hpaste.org/47929 .  Of course it's very minimalisitc here: I don't check for errors, but just a start^^